# Excel Adjust Column Width based on Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a schedule workbook that I have setup to flip between English and Spanish based on a drop down menu located on the **Input Tab**.

Drop Down menu choice will result in cell **I12** equal **1 or 2**.
I'd like for this to determine the **Column D** Width of Worksheets **First Week** and **Second Week**.
If **Cell I12** is **1** Column width would be 3.33(37) , or if **I12** is **2** Column width would be 5.22(54).
Autofit doesn't work as it doesnt also decrease if it goes back to english.

[image: English]

[image: Spanish]

Thanks for Tim's help I got it working. Ran into a little glitch as I forgot to mention the sheets were protected.

I used the following and works fine

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="passwordhere"
  Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("I12").Value
    Case 1: Me.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 2.5
    Case 2: Me.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 5
  End Select
 ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="passwordhere"

End Sub
```

Comment: You should include your current code.  Which exact part of this is giving you problems - triggering the change, or how to apply it?

Comment: Right now it's doing the above with formulas. Only VBA is the Clear contents for the command buttons. I'm wanting to add VBA to Increase and Decrease the column widths. The above was just basic Autofit Column width which is fine starting in English and then going to spanish. It will adjust the column wider. But then go back to input and reselect English the column is left extra wide.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check one work sheet for a variable and then have that control the width on another worksheet(s). Still learning VBA code.... Long time since GW and Q basic in high school....

Comment: I thought autofit would widen the column.  Could it be you have word wrap on the cells in the column and that this changes how autofit works?

Comment: Autofit does widen the column. But autofit adjusts one way. I also want to decrease the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach is to put something like this in the worksheet code module for each sheet where you need to adjust the column width:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("I12").Value
        Case 1: Me.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 10
        Case 2: Me.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 20
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim that did exactly what I was looking for, just had to adjust the width values.

Comment: Actually I'm getting an error '1004'  Unable to set the Columnwidth property of the range class. The problem occurs when I re-protect the sheets. Can that code be modified for a protected worksheet?

Comment: Would it work if I add the following:
`code`
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="sheetpasswordhere"   
  Select Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("I12").Value
        Case 1: Me.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 10
        Case 2: Me.Columns(4).ColumnWidth = 20
    End Select
  ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="sheetpasswordhere"
End Sub
`code`